# calculating degree centrality in Java

Tags: java

I am having a problem where I need to calculate the degree centrality of a user in a certain network I was using R for this purpose but due to memory problem R is not able to calculate the the value as i have a very big dataframe. my data looks like this its a csv file

```
uID1    uID2
6661    1591
6661    28065
6661    42783
6661    3113
6661    21647
6661    3825
6661    29695
1003905 2372780
1003905 7712239
1003905 7456377
1003905 3617193
1003905 2378092
1003905 326275
1003905 1389620
1003905 2970597
1003905 4111006
8484    3062783
8484    12173837
8484    735670
```

The output would be a dataframe of one column uId and other centrality scores like
uID   centrality score

```
6661      20
 .
 . 
 .
8484       2
```

What I want to is to calculate the degree centrality score using java as someone recommend me to use java, but I don't have any knowledge of java I just use R for my analysis purpose. I hope I will get the response.

Comment: The question was put on hold as "too broad". Maybe it could be reopened if you decribed more clearly how you would like to *do* this computation. Do you want a standalone program that reads/writes the input/output as files? Or are you looking for a method that you can call, with certain data structures as input/output? Or are you already using some graph library?

Answer (score 0):

The Java network libs for SNA analysis are a bit limited in my experience. [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) needs tons of boilerplate code and all the generics there don't make it easy to understand what's going on (and the project is dead for ~5 years now), [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/) is great but is a bit volatile, sometimes need cooperation with the devs to figure out some bugs, etc.

If I were you, I'd simply use the [R interface for igraph](http://igraph.org/r/) since you have some R experience. It is written in C so mainly there are no efficiency issues.

Just an example: one of my dynamic network models for my PhD calibrated with data was running more than a week with JUNG, and I wasn't able to boost the performance there easily. The R variant of the very same simulation was done within a day. I know those kind of comparisons does not really say anything, but still, consider it as a side info.

Comment: I am facing a problem in R and is that whenever I run the centrality command I gives me an error and the error is that "cannot allocate a vector of size 2 GB"

Comment: Well, it seems your graph is quite huge then. Have you tried something like [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/)? It was designed to handle huge graphs). Not that user friendly, but handles huge networks, can measure all kind of things and is actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

Degree centrality is just a list of vertex degrees for the vertices in the underlying simple graph of g.

In C# this would be:

```
public string DegreeCentrality(List<Tuple<long, long>> items)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  var total = new List<long>();
  total.AddRange(items.Select(o => o.Item1).ToList());
  total.AddRange(items.Select(o => o.Item2).ToList());
  foreach (var group in total.GroupBy(o => o).OrderByDescending(o => o.Count()))
  {
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\n", group.Key, group.Count()));
  }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Input of:

```
2 1
1 5
5 4
4 6
6 1
1 3
```

[image]

Would return:

```
1 4
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 2
6 2
```

Edit:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\out.txt", DegreeCentrality(File.ReadAllText(@"d:\in.csv").Split('\n').Skip(1).Select(row => row.Trim().Split(',')).Select(item => Tuple.Create(long.Parse(item[0]), long.Parse(item[1]))).ToList()));
```

+comments

```
File.WriteAllText(
  @"d:\out.txt",                                //8) write output here
  DegreeCentrality(                             //7) Use list to generate results
    File.ReadAllText(@"d:\in.csv")              //1) read input from here
      .Split('\n')                              //2) split content to lines
      .Skip(1)                                  //3) skip header 
      .Select(row => row.Trim().Split(','))     //4) split at ','
                                                //5) parse text as number pair
      .Select(item => Tuple.Create(long.Parse(item[0]), long.Parse(item[1])))
      .ToList()                                 //6) Execute results in list
));
```

or with temporary variables

```
var input = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\in.csv");
var lines = input.Split('\n').Skip(1);
var arries = lines.Select(row => row.Trim().Split(null));
var items = arries.Select(item => Tuple.Create(long.Parse(item[0]), long.Parse(item[1]))).ToList();
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\out.csv", DegreeCentrality(items));
```

Comment: I am not familier with C#. how can I load my datafile in C#?

Comment: If you want to use your data file format and not .csv then replace **.Split(',')** with **.Split(null)** and it will split at white-space.